# Why i can't get any response from my node server to chrome browser but it's working fine on postman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

It's a react project. I use multer on the server side (it's a REST API) and i get the files in postman , but in browser it's not working , and i tried simple get request works in postman but not in the browser.
I got this in chrome :

> This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at
> http://localhost:6000/images/ad.jpg might be temporarily down or it
> may have moved permanently to a new web address.

I got this message in fire fox

> This address is restricted
>
> This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes
> other than Web browsing. Firefox has canceled the request for your
> protection.

````
import express from "express" ; 
import cors from "cors" ; 
const app =express() ;  
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
dotenv.config() ;  
app.use(express.json({limit:"30mb",extended:true})) ; 
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit:"30mb",extended:true})) ; 
app.use(morgan("common")) ; 
app.use(helmet()) ; 
app.use("/api/user/",userRoute) ; 
app.use("/api/auth/",userAuth) ; 
app.use("/api/posts/",postRoute) ; 
 
const storage =multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb) =>{
        cb(null,"public/images")
    } ,
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb (null,file.originalname)
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage}) ; 

app.post("/api/upload/",upload.single("file"), (req,res)=>{
    try {
        return res.status(200).json("file uploaded successfully")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        
    }
})

const ClusterURL=process.env.CLUSTER_URL ; 

const PORT=process.env.PORT || 6000 ; 
mongoose.connect(ClusterURL,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true,useFindAndModify:false,useCreateIndex:true})
.then(()=>app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log(`Successfully connected to port ${PORT}`)))
.catch((error)=>{console.log(error.message)}) ; 
  
app.use('/images' , express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')));
app.get("/bitch",(req,res)=>{
    res.json("yo bitch") ; 
}); ```

**i should get the images files in the browser in this address http://localhost:6000/images/ad.jpg**
````

Comment: TLDR - the error is in the code yu have not posted - when it "works in postman" and doesn't work in the browser - usually due to CORS ... or some other client side code error - you've shown the server code, which clearly works, since postman works - now show the client code, where the problem exists

Answer (score 2):

`6000` belongs to a list of restricted ports.

You can either allow (which I wouldn't recommend) this port based on this description

[How to allow a restricted port?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1083282)

> You can create a preference using about:config and allow the port number which Firefox is blocking. Here's how:

> (0) Select and copy the following preference name

> network.security.ports.banned.override
> (1) In a new tab, type or paste about:config in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button promising to be careful.

> (2) In the search box above the list, type or paste ports and pause while the list is filtered

> If the above-listed preference exists:

> (3) Double-click it and add a comma to the end of the list followed by the port number you need to allow. No spaces. Then click OK.

> If the above-listed preference does not exist:

> (4) right-click anywhere on the page and choose New > String

> (5) In the preference name dialog, paste the name you coped and click OK

> (6) In the preference value dialog, type in the port number you need to allow, then click OK.

Or choose a differnt port

Comment: thank you , i have just solved the problem 
But why some ports are restricted ?

Comment: I changed the PORT but still doesn't work.